# What is the difference between the bin() and f string {:b} format

Tags: python

for instance this code

```
i = 16

print(len(bin(i)))
print(len(f'{i:b}'))
```

prints 7 and 5 respectively. Is it not converting an int into binary representation on both occasions? why is the length different?

Edit: I'm a complete smooth brain. I've been working on beginner python challenges and despite what it might look like, It genuinely did not occur to me to just print it and see the difference. Frustration and mental fatigue got the better of me. Cheers to everyone who took the time to answer my stupid question.

Comment: The two strings are different lengths. The first is `0b10000` and the second is `10000`. Both binary representations, different lengths.

Comment: The `hex` and `bin` methods prepend `0x` and `0b` respectively to the output. Format does not and allows for other options like alignment and 0 padding to a specific length

Comment: Please read the docs https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#bin
They include explanations and examples of the "0b" prefix...

Comment: Just looking at the different results they produce would have given you half of the answer to your own question already. Please, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score 2):

Print the actual values, not the lengths, and it's *really* obvious. `bin` adds a `0b` prefix to the string, `:b` alone does not. It's still the binary representation either way (neither is wrong), one of them just explicitly includes the prefix.

If you add a `#` to the format spec, making it `f'{i:#b}'`, the f-string is equivalent. This works for `x` and `o` formats as well, so they match `hex` and `oct` respectively.